# Expected Value of Exponential

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I am attempting to calculate this expected value and am having some serious trouble:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\,\exp\left(\vphantom{\LARGE A}\,\beta_{1}\left(\vphantom{\Large A}\,\left\vert\, z - \lambda\,\right\vert - \mathbb{E}\left[\vphantom{\large A}\,\left\vert\, z - \lambda\,\right\vert\,\right]\,\right)\,\right)\,\right]
$$
where $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Normally I would be alright with these sort of calculations but the nesting of an expected value in an exponential with an expected value has thrown me off. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe I have been able to deal with $\mathbb{E}[e^{-\mathbb{E}[|z-\lambda]}]$ by properties of the folded normal distribution and noting it is a constant and so its expected value is simply itself. Please inform me if my thought process is wrong please. I am still having troubles with:

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\beta_{1}|z-\lambda|}]$$ and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use Taylor series for $e^{\beta_1 |z-\lambda|}$

For $e^x$, the taylor series is $= 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$

Replace x with $\beta_1 |z-\lambda|$

Then $\mathbb{E}\left[{e^{\beta_1 |z-\lambda|}}\right] = 1+ \mathbb{E}\left[{\beta_1 |z-\lambda|}\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[{\frac{(\beta_1 |z-\lambda|)^2}{2}}\right] + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Which is easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the formula in your own comment. The PDF of $z$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*\pi}}*e^{-1/2*x^2}$ and $E(x)=\int xf(x)dx$. So $E(e^{\lvert{x}\rvert})=\int e^{\lvert{x}\rvert} f(x) dx$=$e^{1/2}$. I may have made a mistake in the calculation, but this gives you an idea of how to proceed.